# Event to handle app is closed (Ionic)

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm running a process in background and I need to kill it before the app is closed from recent apps (swiping to right whit the square button).

The app use a plugin to get the current location https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation and another to make the task in background. The background plugin calls to the location plugin, and if you swipe the app during the location is being stored the notification keeps in the drawer.

```
if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

      cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function () {

        if(promise != []){
          $interval.cancel(promise);
        }
        promise = $interval(geolocation_function, 25000);
      };

      cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.ondeactivate = function(){
        if(promise != []){
          $interval.cancel(promise);
        }

        promise = $interval(geolocation_function, 25000);
      }
    }
```

The geolocation function call to the background plugin. I'm using this https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode and I don't know how to control this.

Is there any function I can use for that? Thanks.

Comment: I see a few issues; if you're running this in ionic, you should be wrapping your service calls in a `$deviceReady`; And I assume `promise` is a `$q` object but without seeing its declaration I can't be sure.

Comment: I solved using window.onunload and closing there the service. I keep in mind your advices and I promise to improve my code with them. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this event to close the service before the app is closed

```
.run(function(){
window.onunload = function(){
  backgroundGeoLocation.stop();
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

You can put this three codes in your controller:

`$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', YOURFUNCTION);`

to listen before user leave the page.

```
$ionicPlatform.on('pause', YOURFUNCTION);
$ionicPlatform.on('resume', YOURFUNCTION);
```

to listen when user pause and resume the app: